# DataTable filled from XML does not appear in subsequent function

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I  was trying to import data from XML file and create `DataTable` with data from file.

I used `static DataTable DataFromFile(DataTable dt)` with return `dt`.

```
static DataTable DataFromFile(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader =
        new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"C:\Data.xml");
        DataSet DataFromXML = new DataSet();
        DataFromXML.ReadXml(reader);
        dt = DataFromXML.Tables[0];

       return dt;
    }
```

Later I created `static void CalculateFromXML(DataTable dt)` to calculate sum of numbers from one of columns.

I am beginner and I don not understand why this `DataTable dt` seems like it is not visible in `CalculateFromXML`.

```
 static void CalculateFromXML(DataTable dt)
    {
        int total = 0;
        Console.Write("Total: " + " ");
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
         total += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[3]);
        }
        Console.Write(total);
    }
```

Earlier I tried to do same but with CSV file and it worked perfectly fine.

When I try to print `DataTable` right after creating it (in `static void CalculateFromXML(DataTable dt)`) then it's working, hence I know `DataTable dt` was successfully created. But why it cannot be accessed from `static void CalculateFromXML(DataTable dt)`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataFromFile(dt);
        CalculateFromXML(dt);
    }
```

Comment: You should do `CalculateFromXML(dt);`

Comment: What do you mean by "is not visible in" and "cannot be accessed from" `CalculateFromXML`? Are you getting errors? If so, please post the errors. Is the `DataTable` simply blank?

Comment: You are passing a useless parameter and not getting the return of the method.

Comment: The question is confusing. You say you can print the `DataTable` in `CalculateFromXML`, but then say it cannot be accessed from that same function.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger & checking to see what happens?

Comment: Sorry.. No, I'm not getting errors but when I run a program with code above then it's printing "Total: 0". But when I cut and paste code from 'CalculateFromXML' in 'DataFromFile' then my result is correct - it's printing "Total: 9". Hence it seems like DataTable seems empty for  'CalculateFromXML' .

Comment: You are not taking the return value of `DataFromFile()` and passing it to the second function.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing variable strangely and it is completely useless. You create the object in the method. Simply use that.

```
static DataTable DataFromFile()
{
    System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader =
    new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"C:\Data.xml");
    DataSet DataFromXML = new DataSet();
    DataFromXML.ReadXml(reader);

    // just return
    return DataFromXML.Tables[0];
}
```

Your calculate method is fine, it's the call to the data that is not. Change it to the following. Now the `DataTable` is actually the content the method loaded and passed properly to your calculate method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = DataFromFile(dt);
        CalculateFromXML(dt);
    }
}
```